# regex to remove floating point values

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to remove numbers with decimal places from within a string of text using regex. See here

```
import re
obj = '''This is my #1 user1234@gmail.com <body/> 2 3 4 5 2345! 23542 312453 76666374 56s34534 
        1. _12345_blah@gmail.com 
        1978-12-01 12:00:00 1.23 21.243
        <script>function stripScripts(s) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = s;
            var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
            var i = scripts.length;
            while (i--) {
              scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
            }
            return div.innerHTML;
          }</script> 99.258 245.643.3456!'''
regex1 = re.compile('(?is)(<script[^>]*>)(.*?)(</script>)|(<.*?>)|(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)')
out1 = re.sub(regex1, ' ', obj)
print out1

data = ' '.join(out1.split()).strip()
print data
```

This regex removes most of what I need it to but leaves 1.23, 21.243 and 99.258. I would like to append this current regex to remove those values as well...

regex = `(?is)(<script[^>]*>)(.*?)(</script>)|(<.*?>)|(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)`

Comment: Are you sure you're not just parsing HTML? [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) might be a good idea if that's the case.

Comment: Yeah...This is text from all over the place and I am trying to clean it up a bit. HTML is just part of it but is causing the most problems.

Comment: Obligatory link for people "parsing" non-regular HTML with regular expressions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1301972

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub("\d*\.\d+","",the_text)
```

wouldnt work?  or maybe

```
re.sub("(\d*\.\d+)|(\d+\.[0-9 ]+)","",the_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Joran Beasley! I tried this and it worked.

```
(?is)(<script[^>]*>)(.*?)(</script>)|(<.*?>)|(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)|([0-9]+\.[0-9]+ )
```

What is the advantage of adding the first "d" here?

```
(\d+\.[0-9 ]+)
```